# How to use UR3 with JointGroupPositionController?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-control, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the background is that I want to use the [moveit_servo](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/melodic-devel/moveit_ros/moveit_servo) package with a real UR3.

I have some questions regarding implementation of the JointGroupPositionController and the UR drivers:

1. The github page of `ur_modern_driver` states that the package is deprecated, and the new release is `ur_robot_driver`.
   However, I have UR software version 3.4 and the new driver only supports versions >=3.7. Is it correct that I still have to use  `ur_modern_driver` then?
2. Is it in general possible to control the UR3 with a `JointGroupPositionController`? If yes, how? Do I need a hardware_interface for this or can I use the existing one in the `ur_robot_driver` package just with a new config file?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS melodic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359244/how-to-use-ur3-with-jointgrouppositioncontroller?/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2020-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 1. The github page of `ur_modern_driver` states that the package is deprecated, and the new release is `ur_robot_driver`.
>    However, I have UR software version 3.4 and the new driver only supports versions >=3.7. Is it correct that I still have to use  `ur_modern_driver` then?

No, ideally you would update your controller to at least `3.7`.

You really don't want to use `ur_modern_driver` with CB3 controllers any more.

It's up to you, but you will not receive any support from the maintainers of `ur_modern_driver` if you do use it with your robot/controller, and there are just too many things not working with `ur_modern_driver` and CB3 controllers (which also will not get fixed).

> 2. Is it in general possible to control the UR3 with a `JointGroupPositionController` or ? If yes, how? Do I need a hardware_interface for this or can I use the existing one in the `ur_robot_driver` package just with a new config file?

The latter.

You don't need to change anything in any `hardware_interface`. That's already been provided to you.

You would have to add the controller configuration to the [`ros_control` configuration file for that robot](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/2e44f8629f6332c1a88361e7a202fad8d99dff00/ur_robot_driver/config/ur3_controllers.yaml), similar to [these lines for the velocity group controller](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/2e44f8629f6332c1a88361e7a202fad8d99dff00/ur_robot_driver/config/ur3_controllers.yaml#L128-L131).

In fact, you may actually want to use the group velocity controller already in there, as for jogging, I personally like to use velocity controllers, but that would be up to you.

After updating the configuration (or not), switch the active controller to the group position/velocity controller and that's it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1